# Are there any emulator for the JTAPI API?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jtapi

We want test the JTAPI feature of our application. Are there any emulator for JTAPI available? The testing with real hardware is a little diffcult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gjtapi](http://gjtapi.sourceforge.net/) seems to have one.